# How to skin UI using Forms?

Tags: c#, forms, skinning

I'd like to know if is there a way to "skin" a Form and every widget used inside it. Images should be on background and other elements shall be setup accordingly.

In short, a way to implement a way to display the same Form in different flavors (i.e.: theme and eyecandy UI).

Comment: I've found also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667625/c-windows-forms-theme-support. It seems complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/) makes a WinForms control suite with an excellent selection of skins.

Comment: By handling Paint events and the `WM_NCPAINT` message.

Answer (score 0):

[Telerik](http://www.telerik.com) also provides WinForms components with theme support. I've used their library and it works fine.